# Linking to Google APIs Objective-C Client Library as iOS static library

Tags: ios, xcode, google-api, google-api-client, google-client

I have so far used Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C by compiling the source files directly into my app (as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Compiling_the_Source_Files_Directly_into_a_Mac_or_iOS_Applicatio)). If I were to switch over to linking to the iOS static library (as also described [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary#Compiling_the_Source_Files_Directly_into_a_Mac_or_iOS_Applicatio)), how would this insure that the code works on different architectures?

For instance, if I follow the verbatim instruction I have to compile the static library by choosing a schema (`GTLTouchStaticLib`) and an architecture (e.g. `iOS Simulator: iPhone 5`). If I choose a simulator as architecture, `file libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` reports that the archive contains code for architectures `i386` and `x86_64`. If I choose a physical iPhone 5 instead, `file` reports on architectures `armv7` and `arm64`.

How do I ensure that the `libGTLTouchStaticLib.a` that I'm going to drag into my application project's Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" list (according to Google's instructions) contains all (not just some) of the architectures that might be encountered when my app goes life? I guess `armv7` and `arm64` is sufficient for an app that requires iOS 8, but I'd like to be sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to combine the generated binaries using `lipo` command line tool.

The following [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial) about creating static library in iOS demonstrates use of `lipo` under section `Universal Binaries`

Comment: "The following tutorial": did you foget to add a link? And how should I create several binaries if I have only one physical device and the simulators all use Intel architectures?

Comment: Yep, sorry. I have added the link now. You can use the `xcodebuild -sdk xyz -arch abc` option(s). The tutorial also demonstrates this under Universal Binaries section.